# Avoid Express JS router redundancy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, logic

I am using Express router. For example like this

```
router.get('/view/:uid', (req, res, next) =>{
  Deal.findOne({uid: req.params.uid}).then(function(deal){
    if (!deal) { return res.sendStatus(404); }
    res.render('deal/deal_detail_view', {
      "deal" : deal
    });
  }).catch(...);
});
```

I am doing this for multiple objects that could all have the same way of finding an object: Find one object by it's uid.

Can I generalise this route and inherit it somehow? Any hint would be very helpful :)

Comment: You can put `find` function(s) in separate file and export these functions, and use them in your routing methods. It's that simple and straight forward.

Comment: To elaborate on @MuhammadHannan's comment, you'd create a function with the signature (req, res, next) which runs the `Deal.findOne` code and then you'd use `router.get('/view/:uid', viewController.show);` for instance.